# INSERT array elements from JSON object as table rows

Tags: postgresql, insert, json

I need to insert below JSON value into a table which will have two rows as id `1708,1` and `1708,2`:

```
{
"id":1708,
"types":[1,2]
}
```

Below is what I have tried:

```
insert into table(1708,
unnest(array(select json_array_elements_text('{
"id":1708,
"types":[1,2]
}'::json->'types'))
```

This is complaining for type of types as integer. However, the query also does not look efficient to me. Could someone guide me on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, type)  -- spell out actual column names!
SELECT 1708, json_array_elements_text('{"id":1708, "types":[1,2]}'::JSON -> 'types');
```

Can't be sure since your question does not disclose table definition and Postgres version. Assuming at least Postgres 10. And you may need data type casts.

You need a `SELECT`. A `VALUES` expression would not allow a set-returning function.

Spell out target columns for persisted `INSERT` statements. Or the statement easily (and maybe silently) breaks when changing table columns.